# Как в Electron передавать данные между main-process и renderer-process

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Как в Electron передавать данные между main-process и renderer-process?

Comment: в каком направлении нужно передавать данные?

Comment: Ну хотелось бы иметь возможность передавать туда-сюда.
Например пользователь открыл файл из том-меню (main-process), нужно вывести данные из файла (renderer-process) пользователь их изменяет (renderer-process)  и сохраняет (main-process). Есть ли у этих двух процессов точка пересечения, где они могли бы обмениваться данными, вызывать методы в другом процессе и т. д. ?

Comment: документацию прочитал? https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-main/

Comment: Спасибо. Пропустил этот пункт, в общем оглавлении нет подписей, название не показалось говорящим.

Comment: ipcMain и ipcRenderer позволяют отправить сообщение из фронта и ответить на него из бака но не наоборот. Как инициировать выполнение  функции на фронте из бака я все равно не понимаю.

Comment: вопрос понятен. по ссылке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669727/distinction-between-the-renderer-and-main-processes-in-electron поясняется почему обращаться напрямую из мейна в рендер не является хорошей практикой. однако если таки это нужно сделать: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669727/distinction-between-the-renderer-and-main-processes-in-electron

Comment: мне помогло вначале https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos